# Redux - Specify which reducer from action.type when using combineReducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

So I have a reducer:

```
const buttonReducer = (state = { buttons: [] }, action) => {
    switch(action.type)
    {   
        case "add":
        {   
            state = { ...state, buttons: [...state.buttons, action.payload] }
            break;
        }   

        case "minus":
        {   
            state = { buttons : state.buttons.filter( item => item !== action.payload ) } 
            break;
        }   
        default:
            break;
    }   
    return state;
};
```

Now say I have another reducer (we'll call it componentReducer) that looks similar to this, just with the code in the cases changed. Now how do I specify which reducer it should go to after I've done the combineReducers?

```
const reducers = combineReducers({
    component: componentReducer,
    button: buttonReducer
});
```

Will `store.component.dispatch(...)` work? Or should I just simply rename the cases?

Connection:

```
const Search = connect(
    (store) =>  
    {   
        return { number: store.component.number};
    }) (SearchComponent);
```

Comment: Are you using `react-redux` to connect your component to the store?

Comment: Yes, it's already connected up. I'll update what my connection looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the same dispatch action name for those two reducers, you could use a third variable to the dispatch like `dispatch({action: 'add', reducer: 'button', payload: {..your data goes here..}})`. Then you would also need to add a conditional to your reducer like this:

```
const buttonReducer = (state = { buttons: [] }, action) => {
  if(action.reducer == 'button'){
    switch(action.type){
      ... your code goes here ...
    }
  }
```

Although you could do the above, I recommend you stay away from that solution and stick to naming your dispatch actions according to what they do exactly, like this: `ADD_BUTTON` and `ADD_COMPONENT` instead of just `add`.

Comment: okay, if it's not possible then I'll just rename the cases to `add_button` etc.